# Adding and removing readonly property

Tags: javascript

I'm using Google address form autocomplete.

What Im trying to achieve is, when address is selected and fields are filled, to remove readonly property from those field(i added readonly on input fields to begin with) which are not filled (example: zip code - it's not always filled).

So I added simple code in the loop, but strange thing is that it wont work if I test (val == '') all fields remain readonly, **but** if I test (val != '') filled fields are unlocked and empty remain readonly which is right opposite of what I need. Whats happening here?

```
function fillInAddress() {

        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        var placeid = place.id;
        document.getElementById('location_id').value = placeid;
        document.getElementById('location_id').disabled = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
              var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
              document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;

              //My code           
              if(val != ''){
                document.getElementById(addressType).removeAttribute("readonly");
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `.readonly = true_or_false`?

Comment: Same thing, it works if I try to unlock filled fields but I I try to unlock empty ones its not working